# Ruby on Rails redirect how to pass params from routes file

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to achieve the following:

```
get '/cars/:id', to: redirect('/cars/:id/:slug')
```

slug is also an attribute defined in the model.

I tried other answers like below but not working for me

```
root :to => redirect { |params, request| "/pages/home?#{request.params.to_query}" }
```

Comment: Where is `:slug` coming from? If it's in the model you'll need to route this through a controller method that does the redirect. The router shouldn't be loading models.

Comment: but i can do `get '/cars/:id/:slug' => 'cars#show'` just fine in `routes.rb

Comment: Yes, in that case you've made `slug` a parameter, so that's fine. The router can only work with what it's been given, it's not supposed to go and look things up for you, that's the job of a controller.

Comment: can one do `get '/cars/:id', to: redirect('/cars/:id/:slug')` ?

Comment: I've spent the last two comments trying to explain that you can't introduce new things, only work with what you've got. Make a controller method that does that. Inside the controller you can do *whatever* it takes to redirect to that route.

Comment: If you are looking for some SEO. look at `friendly_id` gem